# How can I check if an array of object with an id values are not present in another array of objects in php?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have two arrays of objects like

```
$array1 = [{id: '12',amount:'23'},{id:'10',amount:'129'},{id:'8', amount:'47'}];

$array2 = [{id: '3', date:'23'},{id:'4', date:'12'},{id:'6', date:'21'}];
```

I want to check all the id (12,10,8) of the first array to the second.
if those ids are not present in array 2. it will `var_dump('not matched')`.

I tried to do this, but when fist element not matched it was stopped to iterate further and show 'not found' status.

```php
 foreach ($array1 as $value) {
            foreach ($array2 as $value2) {
                if ($value['id'] !== $value2['id']) {
                   var_dump('not found');
                }
            }
        }
```

I expect to show the output result after all iteration is done.

Comment: what if you found in array2 ?

Comment: `json_decode()`, `array_column()`, `in_array()` would help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_diff` with `array_column`

```
if(!array_diff(array_column($array1, 'id'), array_column($array2, 'id'))){
  echo 'Not matched';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for helping me out but,
I just found a solution, I use a loop iteration counter.
It counts the iteration number and checks that it completes all the iteration according to the array length.

```
foreach ($array1 as $value) {
            $notFound = 0;
            foreach ($array2 as $value2) {
                if ($value['id'] === $value2['id']) {
                       var_dump('match found')
                    }
                } else {
                    $notFound++;
                }
            }

            if ($notFound === count($array2)) {
               var_dump('not found')
            }
        }
```